# Vue.js should prop data passed on router-view be visible in devtools in browsers?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am passing a few props to my router-view component like so:

```
<router-view :zipchange="zipchange" :accountitems="accountitems" :accountloaded="accountloaded" :profilepic="profilepic" />
```

And I just noticed that when I inspect an element in browser dev tools, all of that data is showing attached to the top level div in each route/page...is this the way it should be? No other props (ones not passed on the `router-view` component) are showing in this way...

Here is an example of what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a way to hide these ugly attributes: You MUST include the prop on the child route or it will be injected into the div as above. I noticed the info was NOT on the pages where I had the prop defined, only on those that did not (where I was not using these props so thought they would be ignored). So for example, on my "Dashboard.vue" page, if I add the prop like so:

```
export default {
  name: 'dash',
  props: ['profilepic'], //<- This must be present on the child
  components: {
    mycomps
  },
  data () {
    return {
      dataitem: somvalue,
// ETC
```

The ugly will go away. Yay. hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. When you pass props to a router-view, the value of the prop is also added to the component's root element as an attribute.

If you don't want the props to be added as attributes, you should use the [`prop` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) on the argument passed to `v-bind`:

```
<router-view 
  :zipchange.prop="zipchange" 
  :accountitems.prop="accountitems" 
  :accountloaded.prop="accountloaded" 
  :profilepic.prop="profilepic" 
/>
```

This will bind the prop value on the DOM element's property instead of its attribute.

Comment: hm, trying it your way I lose the ability of sub components to make use of the data in these props. Can you tell me what use the notation `v-bind.prop` has in this case?

Comment: @Stephen I'd gotten the syntax wrong initially. See my update

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure what that accomplishes. It seems to work exactly the same way as my notation above.

Comment: scratch that, props no longer decend with this notation :( But I found a way around it, see my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but for some reason mine does not work that way. The differences I notice between your setup and mine are perhaps (?) the cause: 1. my props are computed values (not simple inline strings) and 2. My routes are linked to .vue files with separated templates and exports and 3. My routes are named (I read somewhere this affects props)

Comment: Alright. It's hard to know without seeing your code but my answer will hopefully be helpful to someone else